# Upload excel file in codeigniter Error Occure

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

I upload excel file using Codeigniter This code working properly but my localhost then upload on live server then not uploaded

This is my code

function excelimport(){

```
$this->load->library('excel');           
        $file = $_FILES['userfileexcel']['tmp_name'];
        echo $file; 
              //read file from path
              $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

              //get only the Cell Collection
              $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
              //extract to a PHP readable array format
              foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
                  $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
                  $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
                  $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
                  //header will/should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
                  if ($row == 1) {
                      $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                  } else {
                      $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                  }

                   // print_r($column);
              }
              //send the data in an array format
              $data['header'] = $header;
               $data['values'] = $arr_data;

            $count=2;
             for($i=1;$i<$row;$i++){
              $exceldata = array(
                'title' => $data['values'][$count]['A'],
                'quantity' =>  $data['values'][$count]['B'],
                'price' =>  $data['values'][$count]['C']);             
                  print_r($exceldata);  
              //$this->upload_services->insert_excel($exceldata);
              $count++;   
            }
```

}

Error

/tmp/phpYIZkd4

Comment: What error are you getting ??

Comment: Just print this line /tmp/phpYIZkd4   not showing proper path

Comment: what echo $file;  doing in your code? and there is no use of move_uploaded_file() .

Comment: Bro that's not an error that's the temporary path of file.

Comment: i print echo $file then this output print /tmp/phpYIZkd4

Comment: YHee @Nepster please use move_uploaded_file() after uploading and then it wil work after giving from file path

Comment: ok Mayank Bro but this work on proper localhost but not work on live server

Comment: Hi Kool-Mind i add this code but same result             move_uploaded_file($file, $location);